# store SOAP webservice response in PHP variable

Tags: php, soap

Trying to consume SOAP webservice in php. Getting following response after execution of php file:

```
    {"d":{"__type":"BBDetail","BBCustomerDetails":[{"userId":"xyz","customerName":"Anil","MobileNo":"9675483219","Addressline":"8, Highland Park, Mumbai, India","currentplan":"UnlimitedBB",
"PlanExpirydate":"\/Date(1556216940000)\/","Acct_Status":"Active","AuthenticationType":null,"MAC_ID":"00:22:2D:94:79:ED","Device_Type":"Router",
"Email_Id":"xyz@yahoo.com"}],"extTransactionId":"-99999","transactionId":3278125,"returnCode":0,"returnMessage":"Success"}}
```

I want to store each value in php variable in order use it further. Like MobileNo, userId, Email_Id etc.

Comment: Please, take a few moments to read [how to ask useful questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Gone through existing questions but couldn't figure out how to store each value in php variable. I'm new to SOAP and webservices.

Comment: Added following code and getting required fields. Is this approach right ?

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$keywords = preg_split("/[[]+/", $response);
$data=$keywords[1];
$final = preg_split("/[]]+/", $data);
$api=$final[0];
extract(json_decode($api, true));
echo $MobileNo;